# Inserting a variable argument into a Silverstripe template's function?

Tags: templates, silverstripe

I'm using a [pagination example](http://www.balbus.tk/pagination/) from balbus design. In the *.ss* template, there is a line of code:

```
<% control ProductList.PaginationSummary(5) %>
```

Is that possible to use a variable instead of hard-coding the value `5`? For example:

```
<% control ProductList.PaginationSummary(PSSize) %>
```

The variable `PSSize` is defined in the model and will return the number set in the CMS.

Comment: That's the PaginationSummary context. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Hi, depends on the figure I put... let say I put PaginationSummary(5).. the pagination will looks like this: « prev | 1 ... 9 10 11 12 13 ... 18 | next »  where as if I put PaginationSummary(3), it will looks like this: « prev | 1 ... 10 11 12 ... 18 | next » I would like to standardize the context size for all of my pagination through defining variable in my php files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SS 2.4 templating language is very limited in terms of what it can do.

In this specific case, you could try working it out in the controller - try adjusting the `$resultSet` within `ProductListPage_Controller::ProductList` to preprocess the pagination summary to desired context size, so you can access it later from the template.

Try something like that:

```
$resultSet->AdjustedPaginationSummary = $resultSet->PaginationSummary($this->productsPerPage);
return $resultSet;
```

And then in the template you should be able to do:

```
<% control ProductList.AdjustedPaginationSummary %>
```