# RE: Inserting a variable argument into a Silverstripe template's function?

Tags: templates, silverstripe

[Inserting a variable argument into a Silverstripe template's function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314481/inserting-a-variable-argument-into-a-silverstripe-templates-function/9489612)

I am trying to pass a variable to a template control function.
Is the above answer still current for SS3? Or is there a better way of doing it now?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 2):

passing dynamic values to function calls in templates is possible in silverstripe 3.
try the following:

**Page class:**

```
public function testfunc($myval) {
    return 'value is '.$myval;
}

public function testval() {
    return 'foobar';
}
```

**Page template:**

```
$testfunc($testval)
```

this will output 'foobar' in your template as expected.

note that the `control` directive is deprecated in ss3, use `loop` or `with` instead (see http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/templates)